# Questions on how to build a statistical model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

Hey I have some questions about this problem:

You order a large load of balloons for a school festival. You order round and heart-shaped balloons in a ratio of $4:1$. When the delivery arrives, you will see that all the balloons are mixed up in one big card.
They suspect the manufacturer shipped fewer of the more expensive heart-shaped balloons to save money.

Make a test for the hypothesis $H_0:p=p_0=0.2$ against the alternative $H_1: p=p_1=0.1$ with maximum allowed error of 1st kind of $\alpha=0.1$ and the Sample size $n=20$.

So what I have done is:

We have $X=\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ with $n=20$ we have $F=2^{\Omega}$ and every $X_i$ has Bernoulli distribution therefore X has Binomial distribution.

We have that the

Zero Hypothesis is $H_0:p=p_0=0.2$

And the alternative $H_1: p=p_1=0.1$

I think that a test we could choose is $\phi (x)=1_{(|x-n/5|\geq k_{\alpha})}$ with $P_{1/5}(\phi=1) \leq \alpha$ which in our case is $\alpha=0.1$

we have that

$P_{1/5}(|X-n/5|\geq k_{\alpha})=P_{1/5}(x-n/5 \leq -k_{\alpha} \cup x-n/5 \geq k_{\alpha})=P_{1/5}(x-n/5 \leq -k_{\alpha})+P_{1/5}(x-n/5 \geq k_{\alpha})=P_{1/5}(x-n/5 \geq k_{\alpha})=P_{1/5}(x \geq k_{\alpha}+n/5)=1-(\sum_{i=0}^{k_{\alpha}+n/5}\binom{n}{i} p^i(1-p)^{n-i})\approx0,1$

so we find a $k_{\alpha}$ with $n=20$ and after that we are ready for doing our test.

Have I done any mistake? Tomorrow I will have my stochastic exam and this is the last problem where I need to know if I understood the concept correctly. Please help me :)

Comment: $\alpha=0.1$ or $\alpha=0.01$?

Comment: The [uniformly most powerful test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) here is going to be to reject $H_0$ when the number of heart shaped balloons in your sample of $20$ is small, so a one-sided test.  You just add up the binomial probabilities ${20 \choose i}0.2^i0.8^{20-i}$ starting from $i=0$ until you reach $\alpha$.  You may or may not want to take into account that a binomial distribution is discrete

Comment: @Henry sorry I didn't understand where my error is

Comment: If I have understood the problem correctly, this is a simple-type test with Bernoulli random variables. The UMP test statistic in known but has no closed form as far as I know. See [Shao](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553) Example 6.2. p. 396.